# Bootstrap navbar is displaying vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project using CodePen and I'm using bootstrap to make a navbar. But for some reason it's displaying vertically instead of horizontally. Even when I copy and paste code from the [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) examples and the [Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default). I don't know what else to do. Please help.

---

## This is the W3Schools example code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

---

## This is example code from the Bootstrap website:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

---

Both do not work. And  yes, I've triple checked my `<link>` and `<script>` tags.

Edit: [here is my CodePen](https://codepen.io/RyanED/pen/PjBdWd/)

Comment: Did you link to bootstrap library in your document?

Comment: Could you share the link to your CodePen so we could take a look?

Comment: check your browser console, if possible fiddle here

Comment: @trevorp https://codepen.io/RyanED/pen/PjBdWd/

Comment: You're mixing Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 Alpha in your CodePen. Removing Boostrap 4 results in intended behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First like in the comments you are using bootstrap 3 markup and you are linking to both bootstrap 3 and 4 remove the bootstrap 4 css.  Then you need to have the div with the class of `collapse navbar-collapse` so just add this to the div that has the id of `nav` just like the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#about">
        <span style="font-family: 'Source Code Pro', Monospace; color:green"><i class="fa fa-code"></i>Ryan</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"  id="nav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You may want to add the collapse button to the navbar header as well otherwise your links wont show up at mobile widths so it would look like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#about">
        <span style="font-family: 'Source Code Pro', Monospace; color:green"><i class="fa fa-code"></i>Ryan</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"  id="nav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone said - remove bootstrap 4 from loaded CSS files and it will work